# I wanted to display sortable tables on my page but it returns no recods and i cannot see where is the problem

Tags: php

I wanted to display sortable tables on my page but it returns no records and I cannot see where is the problem

```
<?php

$mysqli = new MySQli('localhost', 'root', '', 'statystyki');

if (isset($_GET['order'])) {
    $order = $_GET['order'];
} else {
    $order = 'ID';
}
if (isset($_GET['sort'])) {
    $sort = $_GET['sort'];
} else {
    $sort = 'ASC';
}

$resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT ID, Gracz FROM rank ORDER BY $order $sort");

if ($resultSet->num_rows > 0) {
    $sort == 'DESC' ? $sort = 'ASC' : $sort = 'DESC';

    echo "
      <table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <th><a href='?order=ID&&sort=$sort'>ID</a></th>
            <th><a href='?order=sn&&sort=$sort'>Gracz</a></th>
          
      ";
    while ($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {
        $ID = $rows['ID'];
        $sn = $rows['Gracz'];

        echo "
          <tr>
            <td>$ID</td>
            <td>$sn</td>

          </tr>
          ";
    }
    echo "
      </table>
      ";
} else {
    echo "No records";
}
```

What is solution?

Comment: What debugging have you done, then?

Comment: may i know is it working without `$order $sort` this two variables ?
if not, there is error in your code

Comment: also for security reason add `$sort == 'DESC' ? $sort = 'ASC' : $sort = 'DESC';` before query .

Comment: I've already figured it out. I just had to change names of   $ID and $sn